# Install seq2seq on google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, seq2seq

I have installed `seq2seq` on google colab but when I want to import it I get the error:

```
 **no module named "seq2seq"**
```

When I run:

```
!python3 drive/app/seq2seq-master/setup.py build
!python3 drive/app/seq2seq-master/setup.py install
import seq2seq
```

How do I import seq2seq correctly in this environment?

Comment: Updated code highlighting and added additional context and specifics to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use git and pip to install it.

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/seq2seq.git
!pip install -e seq2seq
```

Then you can import seq2seq module

```
import seq2seq
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I tried with only pip. It didn't work in colab. Then I tried with git. And it worked perfectly.

```
!git clone https://github.com/google/seq2seq.git
!pip install -e seq2seq
```

Then import it and use it according to your need.

```
import seq2seq
```